# How to integrate and programmatically execute 3 different python scripts located in separate Docker containers?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I've got a workflow that needs to use 3 different Docker containers which are built and maintained by 3 different groups of people. Each container has been developed in a "get a bash terminal in the running container and run the python script from there" style, but making the underlying scripts run when starting the container should not be a problem I assume (I'm new to Docker but this seems pretty easy to do). The 3 containers have the following responsibilities:

Container 1: Pull data from a secure company database (using a particular identifier for selecting what data to pull).

Container 2: Translate that data to a form which can be run with a particular model, generating a number of variants of model input.

Container 3: Package up the data generated from container 2 into objects and submit to an external API and retrieve results.

I can run the scripts in container 1 just fine, can go into container 2 and run those scripts on that data, and then go into container 3 and submit the data to the API. However, I would like all of this to happen at a higher-level, say by using docker-compose.

From what I understand, docker-compose can accept environment variables. Is the best way of doing this to set an environment variable to identify my source of data in (1) and then run a docker-compose script with these 3 things happening sequentially? And if I want to do this programatically (say, because I want to repeat this whole process for IDS = [ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, ID_4, ...], to have a top-level python script that loops over these IDs, sets the environment variable, and then launches docker-compose within Python's `subprocess`, or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I'd suggest docker-py or just bash for orchestrating a chain of containers. Compose doesn't have a logical notion of "run this, then that"

Comment: I'm new enough to Docker I wasn't even aware of docker-py. Looks like that package might allow me to do a number of things I wasn't sure how to do with regular Docker. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend telling the three teams their software will be installed on different servers and they need to set up HTTP interfaces, possibly using Flask or Django.  Once they've done that, you can use ordinary Docker container networking; you won't need debugging tools like `docker exec` that require root access on the host.